# image segmentation using pil/any package of python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, imaging

i need to segment an image into regions .i'm using pil.i found no module to segment image in pil. I need this segmented regions as a list or dictionary.

Actually i'm trying to compare the images for similarity in content aware fashion.for that i need to segment the image. i tried segwin tool but it is drawing another image(which is not required and also time consuming)

thans in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to segment an image into regions is creating an other image called labelmap.  The "region 1" is represented by all the 1 valued pixels within the labelmap, and so on. If you need the pixels of the "region 3" you just binarize the labelmap with a thershold equal to 3 and multiply the result with the original image.

Like Oliver I advise [WrapItk](http://code.google.com/p/wrapitk/).

Answer (score 1):

For this task i prefer numpy and scipy. In terms of image processing these two have all you need. For array math i recommend numexpr. Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PIL Handbook](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm), you can use the "crop" function to get a subregion of the image.

Comment: crop() just crops the image .but i want to segment the image.i.e., the image should be divided into regions(a region is a uniform part of the image)

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try the [python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/wrapitk/) for [ITK](http://www.itk.org/), a segmentation tool in C++.

Comment: This is about segmenting (clustering) data, not AFAICT image segmentation.

Comment: Yeah, looks like "Oliver Verdier" did a quick google search of keywords from the question without reading it properly. Notably the word "segmentation". This library is NOT applicable as it deals with CI clustering and segmentation of data, downvote please.